# Create a shortcut to my application in startup

Tags: c++, winapi

I want Create a shortcut to my application in startup . I used visual c++ 2010 and windows 7.

```
HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc){ 
HRESULT hres; 
IShellLink* psl; 

hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 

if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
{ 
    IPersistFile* ppf; 

    psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
    psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

    hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 


        hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
        ppf->Release(); 
    } 
    psl->Release(); 
} 
return hres;
```

}

But, when I was performing not creating. in line :

```
hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl);
```

get error. and not performing Remains my program.

Comment: You should be specific on the error you get, otherwise it's unlikely you'll get appropriate answers to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize COM before performing your tasks:

```
HRESULT CreateLink(LPCSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCSTR lpszDesc){ 
  HRESULT hres; 
  IShellLink* psl; 

  hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 

  if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
  { 
    IPersistFile* ppf; 

    psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
    psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

    hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
      WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

      MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 


      hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
      ppf->Release(); 
    } 
    psl->Release(); 
  } 
  return hres; 
}

int main()
{
  CoInitialize(0); // Initialize COM

  CreateLink("C:\\hello.lnk", "C:\\hello.obj", "hello");

  CoUninitialize();

  return 0;
}
```

Also: watch out for LPCSTR/LPCWSTR (wide) conversions. The hres parameter contains additional information in case you were wondering what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I was performing but not Create a shortcut to my startup. char szPath[160];  CreateLink(GetStartupFolderPath().c_str(), szPath, L"hello") ;

Comment: Really you ought to call `CoUninitialize()`. And it's a shame that you didn't attempt to explain that the `HRESULT` returned carries information. The asker might just carry on, and the next time that `SUCCEEDED(hres)` is false be just as helpless.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer. I'd better not assume anything.

Comment: I suppose I was wasting my time trying to explain things. Looks like the asker just wanted code. I sometimes despair of programmers who seem incapable of reading prose.

Comment: Honestly you provided a better answer than me (way more informative). User has the choice to choose, but I'll put a good +1 on yours!

Comment: @DavidKernin I've got no gripe with you at all. And of course it is the asker's choice. My message to the asker is not to be scared of prose.

Answer (score 1):

The returned `HRESULT` does not just indicate success and failure. In the case of failure, the `HRESULT` tells you why the call failed. When you encounter a failure, you need to decode the `HRESULT` to find out why the call failed.

In this case the call is so simple that there is just one obvious failure mode. You did not initialize COM. With probability very close to 1, the value returned by the call to `CoCreateInstance` is `CO_E_FIRST`, with value `0x800401f0`, which indicates that COM has not been initialized.

You'll want to add a call to `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)` at startup, and match it with a call to `CoUninitialize()` when you are done with COM.

For what it is worth, I think that your function would be better if all of its parameters were wide strings. A function like this should not be worrying itself with such conversions. If you need to make such conversions, then include some helper methods in your code to perform them. You can add a function to convert from `std::string` to `std::wstring` and that should be all you ever need.